# Obtaining a String Between quotations

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class excersie2
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> titlestwo = new ArrayList<String>();

    String path = "C:\\Users\\T-450s\\Desktop\\showtimes.txt";
    File showtimes = new File(path);

    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(showtimes);

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\T-450s\\Desktop\\output.txt");
    while(fileReader.hasNextLine())
    {
        titles.add(fileReader.nextLine()); 
    }

    String movie = "";
    for(String title : titles)
    {
        movie = title.substring((title.indexOf("\"")+1), title.lastIndexOf("\"")); 
    }

    writer.println("\n" + movie);
    writer.close();
}
}
```

Reads the following txt file:

```
Now Showing

Title: "Deadpool"

Duration: 1 hr 48 mins

Title: "Zoolander"

Duration: 1 hr 42 mins

Title: "Kung Fu Panda 3"

Duration: 1 hr 35 mins

and writes a new file containing:

Deadpool

Zoolaner

Kung Fu Panda 3
```

How do I achieve this? I tried using substring but get an error every time.

Comment: what would happen in there were no quotes? or empty lines?

Comment: why is your `writer.println` outside the loop?

Comment: How about changing delimeter in scanner. for example  scanner.useDelimiter("\\"*\\s+");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the error you are getting but I assume it is, I think you are getting an error because the substring tries to find a " but can't on some lines because it doesn't exist and that result in an error so what you could do is to surround the `movie = substring(...` With a if statement to check if "title" contains a ", you can do that like this `if(title.contains(" \""))` also you should put the writer.println inside the for loop